# bad gateway on django+gunicorn+nginx configuration

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

when I try to access my site I only see 502 error.
Here's my nginx configuration:

```
upstream pzw_server {
#   server unix:/home/pzw/pzw/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
    server 127.0.0.1:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_server_ip_addr;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /home/pzw/pzw/log/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /home/pzw/pzw/log/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/pzw/pzw/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
            alias /home/pzw/pzw/media/;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri @proxy;
    }

    location @proxy {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://my_server_ip_addr;
    }
}
```

Gunicorn startup script which I'm using:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME='app_name'
DJANGODIR=/home/pzw/pzw
SOCKFILE=/home/pzw/pzw/run/gunicorn.sock
USER=pzw
GROUP=pzw
NUM_WORKERS=3
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app_name.settings
VIRTENVDIR=/home/pzw/.virtualenvs/pzw


echo "STARTING $NAME"

cd $DJANGODIR
source "${VIRTENVDIR}/bin/activate"
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

exec "${VIRTENVDIR}/bin/gunicorn_django" \
    --name $NAME \
    --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
    --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
    --debug \
    --log-level debug #\
#   --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE
```

Nginx logs following error:

```
2013/08/03 23:26:04 [error] 8582#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: my_ip, server: my_server_ip, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://my_server_ip:80/", host: "my_server_ip"
```

When I try to connect to 127.0.0.1:8000 on my server using lynx everything seems to be fine. Initially I tried to use unix socket, but since it didn't work(same error), I switched to TCP. Gunicorn logs nothing about connection with nginx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `proxy_pass` directive in your nginx server configuration should reflect the upstream server you configured.

```
proxy_pass http://pzw_server;
```

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule

Answer (score 2):

xaxes,

Whenever you set your TEMPLATE_DEBUG to False, you also need to set ALLOWED_HOSTS so that Django knows which hosts/domains to process requests for.  Apparently, the localhost works implicitly when ALLOWED_HOSTS is just the empty list.

I hope this helps!

Comment: by adding ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1'] in application settings.py save my day. Thx